# Returning "0" for NULL values within Dynamic Pivot for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I have the following Code:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),                 
    @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)         

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(month)                   
               from PRCombinedRM    
               group by month,AccountNumber 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE      
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')       
    ,1,1,'')            

set @query = 'SELECT AccountNumber,' + 'FullName,' + 'AccountType,' + 'Company,' + 'AccountBalance,' + @cols + ' from                   
         (      
            select AccountNumber,   
                   FullName,
                   AccountType,
                   Company,
                   AccountBalance,
                   month,
                   amount
                from PRCombinedRM
            ) x 
            pivot   
            (   
                sum(amount)
                for month in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '   

execute(@query)
```

However currently the results that this is outputting shows the values for "amount" as a NULL, however I would like to replace the NULL values with "0" instead.
How would I go about doing this?

Currently the data outputs as such:

```
AccountNumber   FullName    AccountType Company AccountBalance  Aug     Jul     Jun     Sep 
100 M R Test    Test Account    Test Company    100 -50 -50 NULL    -50
```

However I would like the data to output as:

```
AccountNumber   FullName    AccountType Company AccountBalance  Aug     Jul     Jun     Sep 
100 M R Test    Test Account    Test Company    100 -50 -50 0   -50
```

Thank you.

Comment: Show us sample data and expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I would try `coalesce( sum(amount), 0)`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  I've edited the original post to include an example of the current output I'm getting and what I'm hoping to acheive, although this is just a case of wanting the NULL values to show as 0 instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use another variable to store the `ISNULL(someColumn,0)`:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @cols2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(month)                   
               from PRCombinedRM    
               group by month,AccountNumber 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE      
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')       
    ,1,1,'');

SET @cols2 = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(month) + ',0) ' + QUOTENAME(month)
               from PRCombinedRM    
               group by month,AccountNumber 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE      
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')       
    ,1,1,'');

set @query = 'SELECT AccountNumber,' + 'FullName,' + 'AccountType,' + 'Company,' + 'AccountBalance,' + @cols2 + ' from                   
         (      
            select AccountNumber,   
                   FullName,
                   AccountType,
                   Company,
                   AccountBalance,
                   month,
                   Amount
                from PRCombinedRM
            ) x 
            pivot   
            (   
                sum(amount)
                for month in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p ';

execute(@query);
```

Comment: That's perfect, just ran this query and it outputted exactly as I was hoping. Much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `@cols` definition:

```
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', coalesce(' + QUOTENAME(month) ', 0) as ' + QUOTENAME(month)                 
               from PRCombinedRM    
               group by month,AccountNumber 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE      
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')       
    , 1, 2,'')
```

Comment: You are missing the `,0` in the `coalesce`. And this query with the column alias can't be used directly in the `FOR MONTH IN ` part of the `PIVOT`